# Converting a mysql UTC_TIMESTAMP to CST and MST using Javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, utc

I've done endless searching but cannot find a solution that works for me. I am storing records in a mysql database that logs the UTC time it was created (UTC_TIMESTAMP()). I need to present the data to the user (using JavaScript) in their local time. I've tried the following and it is not working:

JavaScript:

```
function localizeDateStr(dateToConvert,divId){
    newDate = new Date(dateToConvert);
    document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = newDate.toString();
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="<?php echo $divId ?>" class="td-short"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = localizeDateStr('<?php echo $entryTime;?>','<?php echo $divId;?>');</script>
```

The UTC date that is stored in the db is the same date that is being displayed.I am not seeing a converted date. Any help would be appreciated. Please advise.

Comment: What *exactly* is in `dateToConvert`? Please provide an example input.

Comment: An example is '2019-03-20 17:43:53'.

Comment: what is being displayed on the screen is Wed Mar 20 2019 17:43:53 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing a string through the `Date` constructor (or through `Date.parse`) is very sensitive to the format of the input string.  With the value you gave in comments `'2019-03-20 17:43:53'`, *most* implementations will interpret this in terms of *local time*.  However, [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-date-time-string-format) does not require conformance of that, as it only describes a very particular format.  Anything else is implementation dependent.

Assuming your strings are consistently in this format, and you want it interpreted as UTC, your options are:

- Adjust the string to include a `T` separator between date and time parts, and end with `Z` to indicate UTC.

  ```
  var newDate = new Date(dateToConvert.replace(' ','T') + 'Z');
  ```
- Parse the string yourself:

  ```
  var parts = dateToConvert.split(/[-: ]/g).map((x) => parseInt(x));
  parts[1]--; // Months are 0-11, so adjust
  var newDate = new Date(Date.UTC(...parts));
  ```
- Use a library like [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/):

  ```
  var dt = luxon.DateTime.fromFormat(dateToConvert,
                                     'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', { zone: 'UTC' });
  var newDate = dt.toJSDate();
  ```

  or [Moment](http://momentjs.com/):

  ```
  var newDate = moment.utc(dateToConvert).toDate();
  ```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you. I went with var newDate = new Date(dateToConvert.replace(' ','T') + 'Z');. Do you have a preference on which solution to go with?

Comment: If you are doing anything significant, I'd recommend a library like Luxon.